# Grouping and indenting json created from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I currently have a dataframe like the following:

```
   ln    7,26    7,27    7,28       name
26443       G       G       G  Product 1
27953       G       G       G  Product 2
```

This is from a csv which is generated daily and the numbers (7,26; 7,27...) are dates, which means they are different every day. I'd like to create a json which looks like this:

```
[{
    "index": 0,
    "ln": "26443",
    "availability": {
        "7,26": "G",
        "7,27": "G",
        "7,28": "G",
    },
    "name": "Product 1"
}, {
    "index": 1,
    "ln": "27953",
    "availability": {
        "7,26": "G",
        "7,27": "G",
        "7,28": "G",
    },
    "name": "Product 2"
}]
```

The current code I'm using to create a json is like the following, but it just dumps it all as is:

```
with open('output.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    df2.reset_index().to_json(file, orient='records', force_ascii=False)
```

Is it possible to make this happen? If so, how?

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#specify columns for converting to dict
diff_cols = df.columns.difference(['ln','name'])

#create list of dictionaries
L = df[diff_cols].to_dict(orient='records')

#remove columns converted to list, add it to new column and convert to json
out = (df.reset_index()
       .drop(diff_cols, axis=1)
       .assign(availability=pd.Series(L))
       .to_json(orient='records'))
print (out)

[{
    "index": 0,
    "ln": 26443,
    "name": "Product 1",
    "availability": {
        "7,26": "G",
        "7,27": "G",
        "7,28": "G"
    }
}, {
    "index": 1,
    "ln": 27953,
    "name": "Product 2",
    "availability": {
        "7,26": "G",
        "7,27": "G",
        "7,28": "G"
    }
}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
In [672]: cols = ['7,26', '7,27', '7,28']

In [673]: dff = df.assign(availability=df[cols].apply(dict, 1)).reset_index()

In [674]: dff[dff.columns.difference(cols)].to_dict('r')
Out[674]:
[{'availability': {'7,26': 'G', '7,27': 'G', '7,28': 'G'},
  'index': 0,
  'ln': 26443,
  'name': 'Product 1'},
 {'availability': {'7,26': 'G', '7,27': 'G', '7,28': 'G'},
  'index': 1,
  'ln': 27953,
  'name': 'Product 2'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

`pandas` doesn't provide such format. Simplest solutions is:

```
import json
json.dumps(json.loads(df.to_json(orient='table'))['data'])
```